# MYSQL error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I'm currently trying to get SSL set up on my mysql 5.7.25 server.  I used the following command to get the process started:

```
sudo mysql_ssl_rsa_setup --uid=mysql
```

And I get the following output when I check for SSL:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | DISABLED                       |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED                       |
| ssl_ca        | /var/lib/mysql/cacert.pem      |
| ssl_capath    |                                |
| ssl_cert      | /var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                                |
| ssl_crl       |                                |
| ssl_crlpath   |                                |
| ssl_key       | /var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the output of my error.log:

```
2019-03-15T19:23:22.155381Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
2019-03-15T19:23:22.155397Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
```

Here are the permissions on my .pem files:

```
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1675 Mar 15 19:22 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     1107 Mar 15 19:22 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     1107 Mar 15 19:22 client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1679 Mar 15 19:22 client-key.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1679 Feb 26 19:51 private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql      451 Feb 26 19:51 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     1107 Mar 15 19:22 server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1675 Mar 15 19:22 server-key.pem
```

I've read some other threads that blame SELinux, but I don't have it enabled.  Some other posts mention apparmor, but my /var/lib/mysql directory is in there with read permissions.

Really at a loss of what else to try here, so any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What settings did you set in `my.cnf`?

Comment: Uncommented the three SSL lines and put in the proper paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling MySQL, reinstalling, and following the same steps.  Not sure why, but this worked fine.